# Lipschitz map with null Differential on a closed connected set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

I am not sure whether this is true or there may be counter-examples.

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ a Lipschitz map. Let $F \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed connected set. Suppose that $f$ is differentiable on $F$ and that $Df_{|F}=0$. Is $f$ constant of $F$ ?

Given some regularity on $F$, that is true. And given high regularity on $f$ Sard's theorem says it is also true. But is it generally true?

I can construct counter-examples in the case where $F$ is not closed like Knaster–Kuratowski fan. But when $F$ is closed, I have no idea how to make this work.